# How to declare lifetime of a funtion

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am using rust elementtree crate to manipulate xml dom elements. When I try to extract a funtion which performs get-or-insert operation, I got some compiling error.
code sample:

```rust
fn find_or_append_child<'a>(ele: &'a mut Element, tag: &'a str) -> &'a mut Element {
    match ele.find_mut(tag) {
        Some(e) => e,
        None => ele.append_child(Element::new(tag))
            .find_mut(tag)
            .unwrap(),
    }
}
```

compiling error:

```
       fn find_or_append_child<'a>(ele: &'a mut Element, tag: &'a str) -> &'a mut Element {
                               -- lifetime `'a` defined here
           match ele.find_mut(tag) {
           -     ----------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
  _________|
 |
 |             Some(e) => e,
 |             None => ele.append_child(Element::new(tag))
 |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
 |                 .find_mut(tag)
 |                 .unwrap(),
 |         }
 |_________- returning this value requires that `*ele` is borrowed for `'a`
```

function signatures:

```rust
fn find_mut<'a, Q: AsQName<'a>>(&'a mut self, tag: Q) -> Option<&'a mut Element>;
fn append_child(&mut self, child: Element) -> &mut Element
```

However, if I use the same code without extracting into a funtion, it will get compiled without any error or warning.

```rust
{
    let ele_xxx = match ele_root.find_mut("xxx") {
        Some(e) => e,
        None => ele_root.append_child(Element::new("xxx"))
            .find_mut("xxx")
            .unwrap(),
    };
    ele_xxx.append_child(Element::new(...));
}
{
    let ele_yyy = match ele_root.find_mut("yyy") {
        Some(e) => e,
        None => ele_root.append_child(Element::new("yyy"))
            .find_mut("yyy")
            .unwrap(),
    };
    ele_xxx.append_child(Element::new(...));
  
}
```

My question:
How can I declare the lifetime of extracted function, since I want to reuse same code rather than write it multiple times.

Comment: Posting a minimal complete example will help you to get a better answer.  One easy solution is to split the `find_mut` and `append_child` &mut borrows, or better yet use an entry API approach

Comment: This is a known problem with the current borrow checker. Polonius should solve that.

Comment: Thank you all. I think they are same cases. Maybe I can request an update for adding an entry api.